# In carbon-components-svelte TreeView: how to change color of children depending on text.?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I would like to ask how to change color in TreeView component depending on some property. For examples I have a tree where are items that were delete and i want their color to be red and they have ID, text, children and removed properties where removed is set to True.

https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/components/TreeView

I have no idea how to do it. I have tried doing {#each}{/each} and {#if} {/if} and it didnt work out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is no good solution to this because the component lacks a slot for templating the items.

As a hack you could abuse the `id` of the items, which is written to the DOM as the `id` attribute of the `li` elements.

You then can use a style to target elements with an ID signaling deletion.

```js
const children = [
  // ...
  {
      id: '1-deleted', // generate this based on `id` + `removed` property
      text: "Analytics",
      // ...
  }
];
```

```html
<div class="tree"> <!-- Element for scoping styles -->
    <TreeView {children} />
</div>

<style>
    /* `bx` prefix is likely to be changed to `cds` (carbon design system) in later versions. */
    .tree :global([id$='-deleted'] > .bx--tree-node__label),
    .tree :global([id$='-deleted'].bx--tree-node--selected > .bx--tree-node__label),
    .tree :global([id$='-deleted'] > .bx--tree-node__label:hover .bx--tree-node__label__details) {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c40dcf1a232c4a889d4d023b10c74045?version=3.55.1)

Answer (score 0):

Since [v0.82](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/carbon-components-svelte/releases/tag/v0.82.0) of Svelte Carbon Components the node in a TreeView is 'slottable' so you can provide your own styling for each node. I think that might solve this problem (based on for example the node.id property).